# extract terms from table wrote with xml files

Tags: python, xml, string, matlab

I am looking for an efficient way to extract terms and its definitions from xml document, i have about 20 documents. i want to extract this data for this code. i want to figure pattern that i can use to build algorithm, so that  the terms like (A) and its definition i can extract them from this xml file.

```
<label>3.3</label>
                    <title>Symbole</title>
                    <p>Für Parameter mit Dimension ist die Einheit in Klammern angegeben, 
                         bei dimensionslosen Parametern ist nichts angegeben.
                        <table-wrap content-type="tabular.form" orientation="portrait">
                            <table rules="all" frame="void">
                                <col char="" charoff="50" align="left" span="1" 
                                 width="5.100cm"/>
                                <col char="" charoff="50" align="left" span="1" 
                                  width="12.000cm"/>
                                <tbody char="" charoff="50" valign="top">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td content-type="norowsep nocolsep" align="left" 
                                char="" charoff="50" colspan="1" rowspan="1" valign="top">
                                            <italic>A</italic>
                                            <inline-formula>
                                                <mml:math id="mml_m19">
                                                    <mml:msub>
                                                        <mml:mrow class="generated type1"/>
                                                        <mml:mi 
                                                     mathvariant="normal">B</mml:mi>
                                                    </mml:msub>
                                                </mml:math>
                                            </inline-formula>
                                        </td>
                                        <td content-type="norowsep nocolsep" align="left" 
                         char="" charoff="50" colspan="1" rowspan="1" valign="top">effektive 
                                            Gesamt-Querschnittsfläche aller Schrauben [mm
                                            <inline-formula>
                                                <mml:math id="mml_m20">
                                                    <mml:msup>
                                                        <mml:mrow class="generated type1"/>
                                                        <mml:mn>2</mml:mn>
                                                    </mml:msup>
                                                </mml:math>
                                            </inline-formula>], Gleichung 
                                            <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="for-36">(36) 
                                         </xref>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
```

can you help me on how to extract this terms with the definition from code like this. i want to figure patterns to extract this data from this code

Comment: Upload a [valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document) and explain what should be the expected output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.